# Is it possible to get access to a previously trained tensorflow model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, model

I have trained/fine-tuned a tensorflow model for 2.5 hours and stupidly did *not* call model.save() or any equivalent method (no checkpoints or similar) directly after fitting the model. I called another method which in turn threw an exception. That means model.save() never got called and, as of now, 2.5h are lost.

Is there another way to regain access to the model? Some kind of cache maybe?

I'm using Python 3.8 and tensorflow 2.2.0.

Comment: If the process where the model was being trained is finished and you didn't set up any checkpointing, then I'm afraid there's nothing you can do. If it's of any consolation, 2.5h is not even that bad, I had to lose a whole day of computer power due to similar reasons before making the effort to checkpoint my training properly (even if you capture exceptions and everything there is always the possibility that your power is cut or whatever).

Comment: @jdehesa Thanks. The thing is that I've got a deadline that ends on Wednesday evening. Anyway, I've restarted the training process now and made sure to care for adequate saving.